# I want to achieve similar background in react native but do not know how to do it?

Tags: react-native

[Here is the backround what i wanted to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U40DM.png)

Comment: one way for you could be using the image background. Use this back ground image in your imagebackground. Like this: <ImageBackground source={require('XXX')} style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', width: null }}></ImageBackground>

Comment: Please read this section on how to ask a good StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @dentemm Thanks for your suggestion, as it was my first question i was not aware, by the way i will be descriptive next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<View>
    <Image>
        <!-- remaining content goes here -->
    </Image>
    <Button>
    </Button>
</View>
```

You can use above curved blue area by using a image background.

Another way to achieve that is by using

borderBottomLeftRadius: number

borderBottomRightRadius: number

in this method you dont have to provide any background image.You only have to make a rectangluar area and then apply border radius to bottom part and then change background color to violet/blue.